# Robot Framework HTML Report Customisation

Tags: robotframework

I need to customize the HTML report generated at the end of test execution.
Few things I require are:

1. Remove the table - Statistics by Tags as I am not using any tags
2. Add the version number for the SUT in the summary section of the report.

What solutions are there for this? I tried to change the robot code and also tried to work on the output.xml. But nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility provided by robot to customize the report and log files, as far as adding or removing sections is concerned. You have two options:

1. write your own report generator that converts output.xml into a format you like, or
2. create a fork of the robot framework source code and make the modifications there.

For the case of putting the version number for the SUT in the summary section of the report, you can add that with the --metadata command line option:

```
pybot --meta "SUT version: 1.2.3" ...
```

That will add the version to the summary section. You can also use the Documentation setting or the --doc command line option to put information that will appear in the report summary.

If you aren't using tags, you should! Those are one of the best features of the framework. You can create tags during a test run, so you could have your tests define a "sut version" tag and set it to the version of the system being tested.